# How to exclude a file from Get Latest TFS

Tags: tfs

I am working with a TFS repository that has one file with a really long filename which is busting the 259 character limit. I cannot change the filename (it isn't mine and it is a deployed service reference filename) but it means that every time I do a get latest it causes a failure, and I have to manually go in and get latest in all the surrounding directories. This is a time consuming PITA.

Is there a way to tell TFS "ignore this file on Get Latest" or "skip errors" so that I can mark this file (Which never changes - or in the rare case it doesn't I'll deal with it) and then just do a Get Latest at the top of the source tree.

Please note I understand about exclude from pending changes, but this isn't a file I am changing, it is just a big nasty sore thumb in the middle of the source tree. (yes everyone else gets this problem, and they hack around it in the way mentioned above.)

Comment: Can you move your mapped folder to `c:\tfs` or something similarly short, if it's not already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that file is in a folder and you dont need any other files within the folder then you can [CLOAK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181378(v=VS.100).aspx) the entire folder.

To cloak folders in a workspace

1. On the File menu, click Source Control, and then click Workspaces.
2. In the Manage Workspaces dialog box, click the workspace you want to cloak, and then click Edit.
3. In the Edit Workspaces dialog box, in the Working folders list, either highlight the folder mapping located under Source Control Folder and Local Folder that you want to cloak, or create a new one. Under Status, change the setting from Active to Cloaked.
4. Click OK to close Edit Workspaces and then click Close to close Manage Workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

> The UI won't allow you to choose a file directly to cloak, however
>   you can choose the file's folder and edit the Source Control Folder path.
>   Meaning you can add the parent folder and set it to cloaked state, then
>   append the file name in the Source Control Path Folder to cloak the file.

Paraphrased from: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aef6aeba-9cc5-4be5-9a5e-af084eead4b5/is-it-possible-to-cloak-individual-files-in-tfs-2010?forum=tfsgeneral#fdf35767-0cf5-4084-b85c-04a359d84ca2

To cloak a folder:

> On the File menu, click Source Control > Advanced > Workspaces.
>
> In the Manage Workspaces dialog box, click the workspace you want to
>   cloak, and then click Edit.
>
> In the Edit Workspaces dialog box, in the Working folders list, either
>   highlight the folder mapping located under Source Control Folder and
>   Local Folder that you want to cloak, or create a new one. Under
>   Status, change the setting from Active to Cloaked.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms181378(v=vs.100)